# Enabling/Disabling Commands

Tags: java, boolean, yaml, bukkit

I have this command in my plugin yml:

```
rankup:
description: Allows to rankup through the prison ranks
aliases: [ru]
```

However there is a configuration file for disabling commands and if you disable this command:

```
rankupstrue: false
```

I need to keep that in the plugin yml in case this boolean is set to true in the configuration file. However, if they disable this I return on the onCommand boolean before anything happens, like so:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender s, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){
    if(main.getConfig().getBoolean("rankupstrue"))return true;
    // code
}
```

I then enable it here in the onEnable

```
getCommand("rankup").setExecutor(new RankupCore(this, qm));
```

However if the boolean that disables this command is set to false and an alternative plugin has the same command, the alternative plugin's command will not work. To fix this I have *tried* to stop enabling it in the onEnable:

```
if(main.getConfig().getBoolean("rankupstrue"))
{
    // getCommand
}
```

However this brings me the same result. I then default back to the plugin yml. Is there a way to remove:

```
rankup:
description: Allows to rankup through the prison ranks
aliases: [ru]
```

from the plugin yml if `rankupstrue` is false?
Or is there a way to add that to the plugin yml if that boolean is true?
Or is there a way to block out this command in any way besides the plugin yml?

Comment: The `onCommand()` method executes just for your plugin. Although different plugins should not have the same commands, your behavior is strange and might depend on externals factors.

Comment: One possible option would be to access the "commandMap" CommandMap field using reflection from the class "SimplePluginManager" from "Bukkit.getPluginManager()". I have tried multiple things myself, I was able to register commands without the plugin YAML, but not unregister them unfortunately. Good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix this problem you would use `PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent` and check if the command is equal to the command that is doing this problem. Make sure you cancel the event after you check to make sure.

```
// in the event
if(e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("command"))e.setCancelled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this clearly, use the event specified `PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent` and make sure that is valid using the `e.getMessage()` method. What I would do is create a space "parser" to create an argument like feel.

```
public void onCommandEvent(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent e) {
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    String message = e.getMessage();
    String[] args = message.split(" ");

    if(args[0] == "command") {
        print(args[1]); // Prints the first argument
    }
}
```

Now another thing you would need to do is check the argument length with args.length() which would return an integer of the length. I didn't add this because this is only an example.

Answer (score -1):

Never put the command in the YAML.

There is no true way to remove a command from the plugin.yml. You're more likely to break a lot of things instead. Listen to the `PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent` and if the command has the name you want plus a true rankupstrue value, cancel the calling of the command and using the values of the event, construct your own event. Use the `getPlayer()` and `getMessage()` methods of the event to do this.